# ASP.NET 4 MVC Web API: Documentation for complex routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

The web api seems to be only suited for the standard use-cases.
But I want to do more complex routing but can't find documentation for complex routing.
If I have more controller, the routings gets more and more complicated.

Can i define several optional parameters with dependencies?
Like this:

```
/api/document/{par1}/{par2}
```

par1 & par2 should be optional but par2 should be only matched if par1 is present.

And are recursive parameters possible?

```
/api/documents/characteristics/{round/green/red-dots}
/api/documents/characteristics/{square/yellow}
/api/documents/characteristics/{square/yellow/flat}
/api/documents/characteristics/{square/yellow/flat/...}
```

Is there a detailed documentation for the web api routing? The microsoft tutorial is too basic...
I need more information about the routing.

I have two controllers and some trouble because two routings are quite similar, so the wrong route is taken. I can use [Action]-Attribute as a workaround, but this feels not right... I also have to consider the order of the routes. This is logical but is nowhere mentioned.
Is the web api only for simple rest api's?

---

**Edit:**
I tried this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{mandant}/documents/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "documents", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

//routes.MapHttpRoute(
//    name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
//    routeTemplate: "api/{mandant}/documents/{id}/{action}",
//    defaults: new { controller = "documents" }
//    );
```

I have two methods:

```
[AcceptVerbs("get")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)

[ActionName("file")]
[AcceptVerbs("get")]
public HttpResponseMessage filedownload(int id)
```

Now I have the problem, the file-action is triggered even if I comment out the second route and the normal get specific document method is not triggered because multiple actions... I tried the [NoAction] attribute but this is not working...
But why will the file-method be triggered if there is no action in the route-template? (Or if the second route is active, why will the normal get-document method not be triggered if there is no action in the url....)
I my current workaround is to set a default-action for all other methods, but this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use routing constraints to set conditions on the routing in global.asax like:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    "ApiRoute",
    "api/document/{par1}/{par2}",
    new {controller="Document", action="SomeMethod"},
    new {par1 = @"\d+" }
 );
```

In the last parameter you can specify regular expression that has to be matched for specified parameter for the route to be used. In the example above `par1` is used for digits only, but you can use any regular expression, like:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    "ApiRoute",
    "api/document/{par1}/{par2}",
    new {controller="Document", action="SomeMethod"},
    new {par1 = @"(value1|value2|value3)" }
 );
```

Comment: Setting the controller static as default should handle the route conflicts. That you can use constraints is new to me. Thanks. A good microsoft-documentation for web api routing would be great. I also found that you can use the * as catch-all parameter like this {*param} but it have to be at the end of the url.

Comment: I found this generic docu for asp.net routing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx